# Force HTTPS request using .htaccess

Tags: http, .htaccess, https, redirect

I have a folder with images, which should be accessed only using HTTPS. How to redirect all requests from HTTP to HTTPS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Search keyword for next time you want to know how to redirect something: mod_rewrite